# RavenDB external config is being ignored

Tags: ravendb

RavenDB's server (builds 2330 and 2380) seem to ignore the --config parameter:

```
Raven.Server.exe --config=another.config
```

The feature has been [suggested and confirmed](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ravendb/C85XplgekUc) and [implemented](https://github.com/ayende/ravendb/blob/2.0/Raven.Server/Program.cs#L131). Are there any constraints on the location of the configuration file?

In particular, I cannot seem to even change the port number unless I overwrite the existing configuration file Raven.Server.exe.config, rather than specifying a new configuration file using the command-line option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be some strangeness in the method we used to get the config.
This command line argument won't work with 2.0 builds. This will be fixed in 2.5

In the meantime, you can set the values explicitly using:

```
Raven.Server.exe --set=Raven/Port==9999
```

Note that the first equal repeat once, and the second repeat twice.